# Remove rows that are exact duplicates of each other

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel 2013, how can I remove rows that are *exact* duplicates of each other (while keeping only one)?

That is, if there are two or more rows where every column has exactly the same value, only one row should remain after the operation.

I would expect Excel to be able to do this task off the bat, but I don't mind using some script if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's Data menu has a "Remove Duplicates" button. Press it.

If you use this regularly, you can pin it to Excel's quick access bar.

Comment: You are right. But for the sake of the community, a better answer would be to be a little more specific than "*Press it*". How about improving your answer with the location of the button on the data tab, and adding a couple of simple steps how to actually do it.